# android won't open google play links from javascript in web-app

Tags: javascript, android, hyperlink, google-play

I've got an html app which is wrapped in Phonegap and in the android store.

I'd like to put a link to the app within the app for users to update if an update is available.

According to the documentation, and some results here on SO, on devices,

```
< a href="market://details?id=com.myapp.name" > Update App </a>
```

opens the store, but I need to open the link from javascript.

I've tried both `window.open` and `window.location.href` but both of those open the browser and I get a URL not found error. The url in the browser turns out to be `http://market://details...`

Anybody know why or how I can link directly to the store, not to the play website?

---------------UPDATE -------------------

I don't want to open the play store in a browser, I am trying to open the native play store.

I know this is possible because smartbanner opens the proper store. 
http://jasny.github.io/jquery.smartbanner/

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that phonegap basically steals the window.open, and was checking the protocol used within. Therefore using `'_blank'` within phonegap doesn't open a new browser window (as you'd expect) but instead opens a browser window within phonegap, which phonegap owns and only lets use either http or https protocols (I'm assuming those are the only two).

In order to pass a link to the system browser, you have to use

```
window.open("market://details?=com.your.app","_system");
```

and that will send the request out of phonegap and open the link in the native browser, which then redirects correctly to the native app store.

Comment: Use window.open("market://details?id=com.your.app","_system"); (?id= instead of ?=) to make Google Play open the actual app page. Otherwise the user sees a list page with the app and is required to make an additional click.

Answer (score 2):

User `target="_top"`

```
 <a href="market://details?id={package_name}" target="_top">App</a>
```

Comment: Thanks `target="_top"` worked well for me. **BTW:** This also works with the actual Google Play link to your app (via https://)

Answer (score 1):

As Google says [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)

Use the format below to deep-link users directly to a specific app's product details page. At the product details page, users can see the app description, screenshots, reviews and more, and then install it.

To create the link, you need to know the app's fully qualified package name, which is declared in the app's manifest file. The package name is also visible in the Developer Console.

**From a web site:** (these will open the dialog of what app you want to take the action: browser or market)

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

From an Android app:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not describing the problem here 3boll, I'll update the question to better describe it. 

The problem is that I don't want to open the play store in a browser (your first solution), I want to open the native play store because I'm in the app. The error I'm getting is when I attempt to open the `market://` link using javascript. It opens fine with a regular link .

Comment: The first link will give users the option to open either in the browser or the store. Not a perfect solution, but not bad.

Comment: I just posted the update @3boll, if you look at the link, you'll see that smartbanner links directly to the app store, no re-direct and no request from the user of what they want to do. But I don't know why that isn't working for me.